# About scope in Python

Tags: python

In this code, `pelts` is defined inside the `with` statement to open a file. The command 'print' is able to access it (Python 2.7). Do code sections like `with`, `for`, `while` not limit scope like a function would?

```
def run_funct():
''' (input_type) -> output_type

Function docstring
'''

# Put the file into a file handler
with open('hopedale.txt') as hopedale_file:

    # Read first line and move file cursor to the beginning of next line
    hopedale_file.readline()

    # We know that info lines begin on the second line, and 'startswith'
    # a `#` symbol, skip these lines after processing the first one.
    data = hopedale_file.readline().strip()
    while data.startswith('#'):
        data = hopedale_file.readline().strip()

    # When the input line no longer begins with a '#' symbol, store
    # the number of pelts on the first data line
    pelts = int(data)

    # Then process the rest of the lines with 'for ___ in'
    for data in hopedale_file:
        pelts += int(data.strip())

# Print pelts
print 'Number of pelts is:', pelts
```

Comment: no they don't limit the scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python **only** functions and classes defines new scopes. `if`, `for`, `while`, `with` etc *do not*!

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, you point out 'in python', do you know if it is the same in JavaScript? I'm currently learning both.

Comment: @hikinthru [Yes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`pelts` is in the global scope so it is available outside `with`. `with` doesn't create its own scope.